# ExceptionsManager.js:61 Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined

Tags: javascript, geolocation, react-native, android-mapview

When I try to run Facebook's [geolocation example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#content), I get the error: 
`Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined` on a red screen. When I just load up a mapview and set the follow user property to be TRUE, the gps is working properly in the simulator.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `RCTLocationObserver` is undefined, meaning `RCTGeolocation` is likely not linked properly.

You'll need to link to it in the build settings as outlined here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/197

Or if you are using CocoaPods, add it to your Podfile.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things it could be. In my case, I was using a Navigator component in the same file, and importing it seems to override the `navigator` global. Try logging `navigator` and seeing what properties are set on it.

If you see 'ProxyComponent', and things associated with gestures, you're in the same boat I was, and doing your navigator.geolocation calls outside of the Navigator file will solve the issue.